# Create new Column based on Regression Model

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have a data set right here

```
set.seed(1)
y <- sort(rnorm(50,100))
x1<- sqrt(rnorm(50,100))+sqrt(y)
dummy <- c(rep("a",5),rep("b",3),rep(c("c","d"),21))

 df<- data.frame(y,x1,dummy)


summary(lm(y~x1+dummy,data=df))
```

I want to create a new column called predictor where I used the **significant** coefficients to predict the values of `y`. Like the formula will be `coef*x1(if significant)+dummy`. I need an automated way to do it because I have multiple data as factors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "where I used the significant coefficients to predict" The word "significant"  rings some alarm bells here. You can use `predict` to calculate predictions  using all coefficients. Using only those with a star beside them in the summary gives you questionable results. You should do proper model building instead or use something like LASSO or elastic net.

Comment: Aggreeing with Roland i would suggest fitting two models:
`lm1 <- lm(y~x1+dummy,data=df)` and `lm2 <- lm(y~dummy,data=df)` and compare them via `anova`.

Then predict the "winning" model via `predict`.
See this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53312/comparing-models-using-anova-function-in-r

Comment: Thanks for the advice but what I want to know is if I their is a function or loop in R to create a column base on the results of the regression model. Say a column that can create a model for each row `Intercept (if pvalue below 0.05)+x1*coef (if pvalue below 0.05)+coef of dummyb(if pvalue below 0.05)`

Comment: R was mostly developed by statisticians. Since no statistician would do that, there is no function for it. It's of course possible, but you'd need to write your own function. Since I firmly believe that nobody should do this, I won't help you with that. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: I found some thing like the `predict` function but I don't think it works if I want used my model on new dataset with different number of rows

Comment: I got a better answer if I used `(lm(y~x1+dummy,data=df))$fitted.values` but I can't used this if I want to extend my data and add new rows